# is it possible to kick off a windows task from a webservice?

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, scheduled-tasks

I have a web service and I'm wanting to create a method to kick off a windows task. Is this possible? I've started by creating the windows task and then using the "when an event is logged". I thought that this would be the option that I'd need, but not sure.

Any help on where to get started would be great. Thanks,

Comment: What is you definition of "Task" ?

Comment: A windows task that starts a job on the machine (such as opening a application / ect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the Windows Task Scheduler you will have to work with the Task Scheduler COM interfaces described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you just want to start an executable you can use the System.Diagnostics.Process class to run the executable in a seperate process.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/). I have used it before and thought it was very easy to work with.